# Does mongoose populate() across N results of a query cause N additional queries to the database? And how does this affect performance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

The title pretty much sums up my question, but for more detail, say I have a collection of houses, and each house can have multiple owners/tenants. These are just an ID reference to my owners collection.

So I want to query ALL my houses, but i want to populate all of their owners/tenants. If my query, something like `housesModel.find({})` returns N number of results, but i ask it to `.populate('owner')`, will it perform an additional query to fetch those owners? keep in mind it can have many owners (for the sake of this question)

So if I query all my houses, and i get back 300 results, but i ask it to populate each doc's owners field, and each house has say on average 1.5 owners per house, is that 450 additional individual queries to the database? It feels like this is not very optimal, but that's what im trying to understand.

If it is actually doing N number of db queries for a parent query of N results, how does that affect the performance? Even more so when we get to the 1000s of results?

Comment: Yes it will populate across N results and cause N additional queries.

Comment: This is not a good schema design.  You should consider embedding your data to avoid relational lookups.  This is the basic principle of using a NoSQL or document-based database solution.

Comment: embedding it wouldnt make sense because i would get a lot of repeated data, considering that im also taking into account that multiple houses can point to the same owner as well. The owner objects are also used themselves somewhere else, and their own data is relevant to other queries without the house data. Perhaps it's too relational a need for a nosql db suppose, but it's what im working with

Comment: Repeated data to satisfy a performance concern is a key difference when comparing a relational database to a NoSQL database.  Microservices very much use this philosophy successfully.  A use case is fully encapsulated.  Repeating data for other use cases is expected in this model, but you need to be willing to think beyond the relational concepts to adopt this strategy.

Comment: So to use this kinda mentality, assuming the embedded data is used elsewhere or might have its own collection, if it gets modified in the other collection, to maintain data integrity then we also need to perform additional writes to modify or replace the embedded data, even if this might occur in multiple places?

Comment: Yes, exactly @xunux. But ask yourself how often the related data changes. If you populated only the first name + last name of the owner, then it's wiser to embed this data instead of relating + populating as the name does not change frequently, but is read much more often.

Comment: Except in a few edge cases (like streams or specific options passed to the populate function), mongoose would populate those documents with one single query. Do those answers above really suggest you'd have 450 separate db calls for each populated document? Or are you referring to "internal", low-level db queries/lookups? 

You could do `require('mongoose').set('debug', true);` to check the high-level queries, but based on my own query speeds of ~2 seconds with a similar design i can already tell that mongoose doesn't do N calls to the db (if that was the question).